# CorePlot display callout when select point is upside down

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, uikit, core-plot

I have implemented the following code in my CPTScatterPlotDelegate to display a callout bubble:

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)plot.plotSpace;
    CPTGraph *graph = plot.graph;
    int yIdent = ((NSString*)plot.identifier).intValue;

    NSNumber *yVal = [[_dataRange yForIndex:index] objectAtIndex:yIdent-1];
    NSNumber *xVal = [_dataRange xForIndex:index];
    double doublePrecisionPlotPoint[2];//[x,y]
    doublePrecisionPlotPoint[0] = xVal.doubleValue;
    doublePrecisionPlotPoint[1] = yVal.doubleValue;
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [graph.defaultPlotSpace plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint:doublePrecisionPlotPoint];

    if(_annotation)
        [_annotation dismissCalloutAnimated:YES];
    _annotation = [[SMCalloutView alloc] init];
    //todo appropriate units
    _annotation.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f kg", yVal.doubleValue];
    [_annotation presentCalloutFromRect:CGRectMake(touchedPoint.x, touchedPoint.y, 1, 1) inView:_view constrainedToView:_view permittedArrowDirections:SMCalloutArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

_dataRange is just a custom class holding my data and _annotation is the instance of my callout.

The problem is I cant't get the position of the callout working properly. If I set _view to the ViewController.view I get the right callout but in the wrong place like this:

[image: Clicked point in yellow]

If I set _view to the CPTGraphHostingView instead I get the right point but the callout appears to be flipped like this:

[image]

How to I get the right plot point co-ordinates to display the callout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add any subviews to the hosting view—it uses a flip transform on iOS so Core Plot can share drawing code between iOS and the Mac.

Use the `-convertPoint:toView:` or `-convertPoint:fromView:` method to convert `touchedPoint` from the hosting view's coordinate system to the `ViewController.view` coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks Eric that worked great, I used the method: [graph convertPoint:touchedPoint toLayer:_view.layer] though. Same thing I guess?

Comment: I'm using this
`CGPoint convertedPoint = [plot.graph convertPoint:touchedPoint toLayer:self.view.layer];`
And its still off by a little bit, sitting to the left of the point and down... does graph padding affect this?

Answer (score 0):

I have subclassed `CPTGraphHostingView` for a few charts so as an alternative I found any subview you add to it you should do the following:

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(1.0, -1.0)
```

This doesn't change the fact that the coordinate system is (0,0)-bottom-left but the UIView you add will draw the right way up when rendered. Still use [Eric's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309408/622276) for translating between coordinate systems but for anyone that finds themselves here trying to add a subview to `CPTGraphHostingView` I hope this helps.